# How to Call a third party program for each item in a list one by one in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that will unrar a set of files and then run a third party program on each of the unrar'd files one by one. I can get it to unrar the files correctly, and it will run the third party program (wxPirs.exe) on the first unrar'd file but then it stops. The code I have so far is below.

```
static void unpackRar()
{
    string homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string packedPath = homePath + "\\XBLA\\";
    string unpackedPath = homePath + "\\XBLA_Unpacked\\";
    string unrarPath = homePath + "\\unRAR.exe";

    {
        var process = Process.Start(unrarPath, " x " + packedPath + "*.rar  " + unpackedPath);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

static List<string> GetAllFiles(string unpackedPath)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(unpackedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}

static void unPirs()
{
    string homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string unpackedPath = homePath + "\\XBLA_Unpacked\\";
    string wxPirsPath = homePath + "\\wxPirs.exe";
    for (int i = 0; i < GetAllFiles(unpackedPath).Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetAllFiles(unpackedPath)[i]);
        var process =  Process.Start(wxPirsPath, GetAllFiles(unpackedPath));
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

I have tried using a for loop and `Process.WaitForExit`, but that did not seem to work as I expected it to.

Comment: `i < GetAllFiles(unpackedPath).Count` oh my god, you're recursively searching your file system information for three times the amount of files you find. I thought I knew insanity, but you, my friend, have surpassed my entire life experience with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, regarding the comment: they are right. You can **GREATLY** improve performance by changing that method to only call `GetAllFiles()` once, and especially not again for every loop iteration.

Second, regarding the issue in the question, I noticed the call to `Process.Start()` is missing the `[i]` after `GetAllFiles()`. Again, you want to use this on a variable from a single call to the method, rather than calling it again each time in the loop. To help avoid that kind of mistake in the future we can also use a `foreach` loop rather than a `for` loop.

Put it all together like this:

```
static void unPirs()
{
    string homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string unpackedPath = homePath + "\\XBLA_Unpacked\\";
    string wxPirsPath = homePath + "\\wxPirs.exe";
    var files = GetAllFiles(unpackedPath);

    for (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        var process =  Process.Start(wxPirsPath, "\"" + file "\"");
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

If it were me, this also seems like a good case for some asynchronous programming. I might queue up several `Task`s to have going all at the same time (typically 2 * the number of CPU cores is a good starting place). Every time one finishes add another until they are all running. Then, wait for them all to finish.

Comment: Thanks so much, that definitely solved the problem. It did open up a new one where the third party program I'm launching doesn't like the spaces in the file names, so instead of seeing \Castle Crashers, it just sees \Castle which doesn't. I will have to look into that a little bit more

Comment: I updated my answer to add quotes around the file name, which should help.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I wrote this same program in Python and only had trouble with a few parts but I’m trying to relearn c# after a decade of not using it and I’m finding moving from Python to this more difficult than I thought it would be lol